# jsPDF not working for IE 7/8 as well as Firefox 13?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am trying out the sample code for jsPDF for IE7/8 and Firefox 13. In IE it displays a script error stating

`the data area passed to a system call is too small jsPdf.js`

On the other hand I dont see an error on Firefox's console. I tried it out in Chrome and it works great. I searched through but in most of the places the replies I got was or I must say what I came across is that it works fine with all the browsers. But in my case even the sample application is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

With Chrome the generation of the new pdf page worked great, while in Firefox it stopped and could not be completed.

I solved so:

open the jspdf.js file and go at line 1698, there you find this

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
return API.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}
```

and substitute it with

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
return API.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}
else {
return API.output('dataurl');
}
```

in this way the switch statement that follows will find the right case to compile the URL in a working way for firefox